# BindableApplicationBar doesn't fire tap events

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I need an ApplicationBar which can be bound to both commands and tap events (tap events are needed for UI related stuff and I can't handle them in my Model).

I'm trying with BindableApplicationBar from NuGet and the command binding works fine but there's no way to get the tap events.

Please note that I'm changing the `DataContext` to make the binding work but the `Tap` event has to be managed in the code-behind (and I don't know if this may be the main cause of my problem!)

Here's the bar's xaml:

```
<bindableApplicationBar:Bindable.ApplicationBar>
    <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar>
        <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBarButton
            Text="{Binding MainSearchText}"
            IconUri="Assets/AppBar/feature.search.png"
            Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
            Name="SearchBarButton" />
        <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBarButton
            Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AppBarSettingsText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
            IconUri="Assets/AppBar/feature.settings.png"
            Tap="SettingsButton_OnTap" />
        <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBarMenuItem
                Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AppBarAboutText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                Tap="Info_OnTap" />
        </bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </bindableApplicationBar:BindableApplicationBar>
</bindableApplicationBar:Bindable.ApplicationBar>
```

and here's one of the handlers that I have in my .xaml.cs file:

```
private void Info_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    _about.Show();
    Debug.WriteLine("INFO ON_TAP");
}
```

No "INFO ON_TAP" line is written when I click on the `MenuItem`.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you put a breackpoint is your method, you pass?

Comment: Yeah, the method is not even called

Comment: Why you don't use click or command? And i think when you tap on button, it's doesn't work but pass if you tap on the screen no?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you would use BindableApplicationBar. BindableApplicationBarButton inherits from FrameworkElement (and thus has Tap event) to support DataContext and Bindings; the Tap event is not fired because no BindableApplicationBarButton is ever tapped, no BindableApplicationBarButton is ever onscreen - this is only a wrapper that creates an ApplicationBarIconButton, but doesn't pass the Tap event handler to it (ApplicationBarIconButton, by the way, has only one event - Click). The same goes for BindableApplicationBarMenuItem. BindableApplicationBar works best with Commands.

See more in comments in source: [BindableApplicationBar @ codeplex](http://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Here are (some of) your options:

- use Command property of BindableApplicationBarButton to react to buttons clicks
- after defining BindableApplicationBar in xaml, hookup to Click events of ApplicationBarIconButtons it created in *code behind*
- use BindableApplicationBar code (open source) and alter it for best experience in your scenerio

Answer (score 0):

You can try Cimbalino Toolkit AppBar ... much more powerfull and easier to use!

For example:

```
 <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <cimbalinoBehaviors:MultiApplicationBarBehavior 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=MainInfo, Converter={StaticResource HomeMenuConverter}}" >

            <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBar Opacity="0.5"  
                                               IsMenuEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}">


                <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton 
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAuthenticated}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding GetFavorites, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    IconUri="/Assets/appbar.sync.rest.png" Text="{Binding Labels.Translation.Refresh, Source={StaticResource LabelsManager}}" />
                <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton 
                    IsVisible="{Binding SelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding SetSelectionMode, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    IconUri="/Assets/ApplicationBar.Select.png" Text="{Binding Labels.Translation.Select, Source={StaticResource LabelsManager}}" />
                <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton 
                    IsVisible="{Binding SelectionMode}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteFavorites, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    IconUri="/Assets/ApplicationBar.Delete.png" Text="{Binding Labels.Translation.Delete, Source={StaticResource LabelsManager}}" />

                <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton 
                    IsVisible="{Binding SelectionMode}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding SetSelectionMode, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    IconUri="/Assets/ApplicationBar.Cancel.png" Text="{Binding Labels.Translation.Cancel, Source={StaticResource LabelsManager}}" />

            </cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBar>
        </cimbalinoBehaviors:MultiApplicationBarBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit